# Can I use ASP.NET Core with IIS WindowsAuthentication? What about role membership?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, active-directory, identity

Suppose I'd like to use ASP.NET Core in an intranet project, where I want to enable single sign-on for users based on their AD Identity. The project needs to have different roles assigned per user and associated with these identities.

Can I? There is not much information online about it.... but here is what I've found:

#### What I've done...

In VS2017 I just created a new ASP.NET Core project and selected `Windows Authentication` as my authentication mechanism. If I run this project locally, IIS correctly passes my **local** `WindowsIdentity` to the application (my machine is not part of the domain) and I can access the user's claims.

*My question is:*

Will this same behavior hold in a server that is domain joined, and for a user that is part of the directory? Will IIS correctly pass AD credentials to or the WindowsIdentity object to my asp.net core application?

Bonus:

How could I handle roles in this scenario? I am thinking either through claims configured directly in the directory (assuming IIS can hand me that information) or to manage the roles myself based on a user claim (like username). Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, it will work the same way. I'm doing it on my project.

Comment: _ASP.NET Core , IIS, WindowsAuthentication, and roles_ This is not a question title, its a list of tags/keywords. Is it so hard to summarize your problem into one short sentence?

Comment: Good suggestion @Tseng - the form to communication style is a bit rude, but you have a point.  Title updated.